# Ms Access Field with Year and Week

Tags: ms-access-2013

Newbie here. On Ms Access 2013, I wanted to create a field that is incrementing and with prefix. The field is the table's primary key. The expected output of the field will be RMYYWWxx where, RM is constant, YY is last 2 digit of the current year, WW is the current calendar week, and xx will be the incrementing value. I also need to have the sequence revert back to 01 once the data is entered on the succeeding calendar week. (e.g. RM182003, will create RM182101 if the data is entered on calendar week 21). Is this possible? Or how can I work around these requirements?Appreciate your help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, here is how to get the year-week from a date.

You can easily modify it to return RMyyww: RM1820

Then use *DMax* to look up the latest/highest value recorded:

```
YearWeek = "RM1820"
NextNo = YearWeek & Format(Val(Right(Nz(DMax("[NumberField]", "YourTable", "[NumberField] Like '" & YearWeek & "*'"), YearWeek & "00"), 2)) + 1, "00")
```